# Search for data/values/keyes in firestore documents

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a search screen in my app and i want to make sure you can search for every value in a firestore document. There are always 4 Keys in one document: title, author, genre and code.

```
getBookbyTitel(query) async{
    return await Firestore.instance
        .collection("book")
        .where("titel", isEqualTo: query)
        .getDocuments();
}
```

but with this code, I am only able to search for the title. how can I search for the three other keys a well?
Thanks

Comment: Add another `.where`.

Answer (score 0):

```
    getBookbyTitel(query) async{
        return await Firestore.instance
        .collection("book")
        .where("titel", isEqualTo: query).where("author", isEqualTo: query2).where("genre", isEqualTo: query3).
where("code", isEqualTo: query4).getDocuments();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Firestore has the advantage of having indexes complex and simple.

```
getBookbyTitel(query,query2,query3) async{
return await Firestore.instance
.collection("book")
.where("genre", isEqualTo: query)
.where("title", isEqualTo: query2)
.where("code", isEqualTo: query3)
.getDocuments();
```

There is no actual limit to how many .where() you can use, however this is what is called a "complex query" and as such the first time will fail because firestore needs to index first.

So, first run the code above, in the console an error message will pop up with a url that will send you to your firebase project and then on its own it will start indexing so the next time you run that code it will do it lightning fast.

However there is a downside, for each .where() you use, an additonal indexation will be needed for it to work properly. Have in mind that the order is important too, if you query in order [title,author,genre,code] you should always do it this way, otherwise it will detect it as a completely different query and will ask you to index again.

Finally there is also the issue that for example a more specific query is not the same as a query with less attributes. i.e:

```
getBookbyTitel(query,query2,query3) async{
return await Firestore.instance
.collection("book")
.where("genre", isEqualTo: query)
.where("title", isEqualTo: query2)
.where("code", isEqualTo: query3)
.getDocuments();
```

If you have this query, and then you try this instead:

```
getBookbyTitel(query,query2,query3) async{
return await Firestore.instance
.collection("book")
.where("genre", isEqualTo: query)
.where("title", isEqualTo: query2)
.getDocuments();
```

It won't work, it will ask you for another index.